# LookUpEdit many-to-many

Tags: xaml, many-to-many, devexpress, bind

I have this relation:

PRODUCT  o---o< PRODUCTCATEGORY >o---o  CATEGORY

Category information to show to the user: Name

This information loads from database correctly to the model (EF Core 2). The problem i can't resolve is to use LookUpEdit for choose different categories to a product and show this selection at the text control. Of course, i need to show ALL the categories to the user first, but i need to load the previosly database saved product's categories too when the product is selected.

Then essential problem is that i try to work with one criteria ( product.ProductCategory.Category ) but LookUpEdit binds at the start with all the categories:

LOOKUPEDIT XAML CODE:

```
<dxg:LookUpEdit ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" IsTextEditable="False"  EditValue="{Binding Product.ProductCategories, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource CategoryConverter}}">
```

AND CATEGORY CONVERTER CODE:

public class CategorYConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
    {
        public CategorYConverter() { }

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            if (value is ObservableHashSet<ProductCategory>)
            {
                ObservableHashSet<ProductCategory> ProductCategories = value as ObservableHashSet<ProductoCategory>;
                return new List<object>((ProductCategory.Select(c => c.Category)));
            }

        }

        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

I can load producselected categories but i can't resolve when the user chooses a category from the lookupedit. It doesnt bind correctly to lookupedit. So i can't work with the both solutions together.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found out the problem: when the user select categories from the lookupedit category control, the ConvertBack function is called. So I only needed to 'transform' the data received to the data that expects the EditValue Binding:  Product.ProductCategories. Exactly in the same format, in my case an ObservableHashSet

```
 public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {

        IList<object> map = value as IList<object>;
        ObservableHashSet<ProductCategory> pc = new ObservableHashSet<ProductCategory>();

        foreach (var m in map)
        {
            pc.Add(new ProductCategory() { Category = m as Category });                
        }

        return pc;
    }
```

Hope this helps someone